# What are the rules for merging two relations in a schema?

Tags: database, merge, schema

For example I have created a relational schema (for an online bookstore) after decomposing relations and getting them to 3NF.  Here are two of the relations.

```
ShoppingCart(CartID{PK}, TimeStamp)
CustomerCart(CartID{PK and FK}, Email)
```

Can these merge? Is the only rule to merge these two together that they need to have the same primary key?  What about CartID in customer cart also being a foreign key?

Comment: They can't have the same primary key otherwise it wouldn't be a primary key. You can merge the two if the primary key of one table is included somewhere in the other (foreign key).

Comment: Do you have any resources you can link me to that explains merging?  Also this example is of decomposed relations and made to be in 3NF.  So my understanding was that you create the final schema by merging any relations that have the same primary key.

Comment: @Darkisa What does "They can't have the same primary key otherwise it wouldn't be a primary key" mean? They *do* both have "the same PK" CartID.

Comment: Please explain exactly what "merge" means. Otherwise you have not asked a question. What we would expect is that you mean you would use the join of the tables instead of the individual tables. This is because in normalization we use components that join to an original instead of the original itself. The topic is 'lossless-join decomposition'. Also, do you mean the result has to be 3NF?

Comment: The question wasn't related to joins.  It's about having a badly written schema that has relations not in 3NF, decomposing them to fit with the ER model, then combining/merging any relations that have the same primary key.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb* for merging is that there should **not** be any information (column) in your resulting table that does not relate directly on the primary key (that is called [transitive dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency)).

And of course that the relationship is 1 to 1. (not `1:1` in DB notation sense but that each entry in either table should match exactly one entry in the other)

So, in your case, if the CustomerCart(Email) directly relates to the same ID as the ShoppingCart(CartId) (because it is a foreign key AND also primary key which ensures uniqueness), then you can merge them.

(*) this rule alone is not sufficient, see the documentation for all the rules.

Comment: Perfect, the exact answer I was looking for.

Comment: @crazyPen & Simon The transitive FDs that matter to 3NF are transitive FDs of non-prime columns on candidate keys, and there being none is not sufficient, because a table must also be in 2NF. The very link given makes that clear; it says "it excludes certain types of transitive dependencies" and and it references 3NF. So this answer is not correct. The "1 to 1" is also incorrect (common columns must be a superkey of one table). Also this case *isn't* 1:1. Also the reasoning about "foreign key AND also primary key" is wrong. You can't merge them. See my answer.

Comment: Without further details in the question, I have supposed that the OP know about NF and hence that the 2 tables given are meeting preconditions. In the end, your answer says that if there is a 1 to 1 relation (exactly one to exactly one which excludes NULL in the join), then he can merge... which is what I said.

Comment: @Simon What you said is wrong, as I explained. Also I said that 1:1 was *neither necessary nor sufficient*. And that this is *not* a 1:1 case and they *can't* be replaced by their join. So your comment does not reflect what my comment or my answer says. Also your "supposed" is unclear since the OP *is asking for preconditions*. (PS "there should not be any information (column) in your resulting table that does not relate directly on the primary key" is too vague to be useful. It's good that you try to clarify with "transitive dependency", but you don't actually use the term to say something.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the OP says he _has_ 3NF and therefore _if_ the result is 2 tables, then there is a reason for that and indeed he cannot merge as the answer is in the question. However, there is _no_ schema definition case where a join may not have nulls and therefore no 2 tables can never be merged. The second part of your answer imposes a condition to allow the merge which is phrased differently but means the same as I said as an _of course_ condition.

Comment: Neither that comment nor your edit address the misreading, misinformation and lack of clarity I explain in my comments, which I stand by.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about normalization. The only rule for the general case is that after you join the table is in the NF you want. In certain special cases for the two relations you could know their join is in that NF. In this case you can't replace them by their `JOIN` because ShoppingCart rows that don't have a CartID in CustomerCart won't be in the join.

You don't say what you mean by "merge", but if you modify CustomerCart to have the same set of CartID values as ShoppingCart by having NULL for Emails for added CartID values, then you can replace the two tables by their join. Ie `ShoppingCart LEFT JOIN CustomerCart` contains the same info as the two tables.

Comment: When I say merge i meant being able to write the two like this ShoppingCart(CartID, TimeStamp, Email).  Also both were already in 3rd normal form and were decomposed from other relations.   I believe Simon's answer was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I expected you to mean that heading, but you haven't explained what it's supposed to hold. Please give a query for its value, and edit it into your question. Re the other answer (which, I explain, says a lot of wrong things), it does not explain what *it* means by merge either. Just note, as I explain in my answer and comment, that if 'merge' means JOIN then merging loses information, but if it means ShoppingCart LEFT JOIN CustomerCart you are ok.

Comment: It's a homework exercise for an online bookstore.  Basically we were given an ER model and the Schema was written incorrectly.  Our job was to rewrite the schema by decomposing each relation into 3NF.  We were also told that where possible we should combine the relations (merge).    My understanding is that these two relations will be combined and NOT joined.  But if it was a join then I would guess it would be a left outer join.  We were not using queries for this which is why I tried to keep the question as simple as I could.  Sorry if there was confusion in how I worded it.

Comment: You are using "combine" and "merge" yet you don't say what you mean by them. So how can you get an answer? Use enough words to actually say something concrete. 1. When we decompose by normalization, the components join back to the original. 2. If you have tables that describe your situations but you want different tables that describe your  situations, then the the latter can be expressed as queries/views of the former. Or you can give a statement template that a row makes into a true statement when it's in a table. A schema & constraints is not enough to know what a table is for.

Comment: ... For a decomposition, the query/view of a component is a projection of an original. When we *don't* decompose when we could, the original is still the join of the components. Here if your "merged" table is always set to R1 JOIN R2 you lose info, but not if it is always set to R1 LEFT JOIN R2. PS Where do you think constraints come from? (Including FDs, CKs & FKs.) We need to know each table's predicate (how it maps a business situation to a table value) and what situations can arise (per business rules). Then we know that for each table only some values can arise.

Comment: The situation where you say `then you can replace the two tables by their join` never holds as a rule because it depends on the data in both tables at a given time. The fact that a join does not contain NULL does not mean there cannot be any afterward (except with circular primary-foreign keys which is theoritically valid but practically a nightmare). Thus it cannot be applied as a rule to determine if you can merge the tables.

Comment: @Simon I can't make much sense of your comment. It can't contradict anything I said, since what I said is correct. Two components of a table can be losslessly joined if one of them satisfies a FD and the determinant of the FD is a key of one of the tables. Since they are components of the same table, they have the same set of subtuple values for their common attributes. (This is called an equality dependency, expressible as you say by two FKs.) If we happen to have designed those two tables separately, they can be replaced by the join....

Comment: @Simon ...  When they share a CK, their join can *obviously* replace them so they just don't come up separately: employee(e,name) & employee(e, address) obviously become employee(e,name,address). Other times that two bases can be losslessly joined they would have been the components from a normalization if you happened to have started with the join: employee(e,name) & departments(e,d) with CK {e,d} vs employee_stuff(e,name,d).

Comment: @philipxy FD is not comutative and with CK they depend on the actual data, hence you cannot ever use this theory to answer a practical case. The OP's question (even though formulated as much more general) is about a practical case with an easy answer to be given. There are indeed lots of things not explicitely mentionned in the question but that just make sense when you read it. You are arguing about those and throw outer notions in the game which are surely important, but not a matter for the OP because it is implied. If you want to write a proper global answer, please do so extensively.